# Recover an answer.

Tags: discussion, specific-answer, deleted-answers

I want to recover the answer to this question [Equivalent statement for bounded derivative implies Lipschitz in $\mathbb{R^n}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471210/equivalent-statement-for-bounded-derivative-implies-lipschitz-in-mathbbrn) but the thing is that I forget the user that post it and I want to recover that information, What can be done in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: If you [use Google](https://www.google.com/search?q="Equivalent+statement+for+bounded+derivative+implies+Lipschitz"), can you see in the Google cache (some version of) the answer you are looking for?

Comment: mmm I am not very familiar with that, can you clarify please? :)

Comment: Simply try [this link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471210/equivalent-statement-for-bounded-derivative-implies-lipschitz-in-mathbbrn). It should be link to the cached version of that page.

Comment: BTW you should probably clarify in your post what you mean by "recover an answer". Do you mean that you want to undelete it, or just that you want to see the text of the answer? (And BTW the link in your post is a link to an answer, not to a question.)

Comment: Right, But that is not the answer I want :), so I want to see the answer only, because I think I can't undelete it since I didn't answer my question :)

Comment: I have tried that link but the thing is that I can't see the answer quite well, is there another way to get it?

Comment: The cached version is an older version - the answerer has edited and deleted it since then. It can be undeleted if either the poster or enough 20k+ users vote to undelete. And any 10k+ users can see deleted the post, so any such user can provide you with the current version of the post. Since I do not know the reasons why the answerer decided to delete their post, I feel a bit uncomfortable about doing this. So you can simply wait if somebody gives you the text of the deleted answer. Or you could try [to ping](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comment-replies) the answerer...

Comment: ...The later possibility seems a bit better to me, since you might also get an explanation why they decided to delete the answer. (You now know the name of the user who answered your post from the cached version. So if you think that it will not bother him too much, you can try to find some his post and ask him there; probably adding link to your post on meta would also be a good idea.)

Comment: Ok, let me try both ideas just give a while :)

Comment: I am sorry to bother you. That's nothing to do with you. I am just checking whether deleting my own answer will in any way change my rep. (And I don't expect you to come back so fast!). The answer is undeleted now.